# Hovering functionality in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So I have a problem with hovering. The thing I am trying to accomplish is. So in here you can see the conditionally rendered component, which has toggle functionality. When I press on the Img the Control component opens up. When I hover on that img I have hover functionality, when its hovered it displays the new img, When I click into that img the Control Component opens up inside of that Hover funcionality I have a REACT Icon which when press closses everything which I want, but when I hover into that img nothing shows, so It only happens once/in the first render. Which I don't want. I KNOW THE CODE is Messy and hard to understand, but if you could help me I would be very grateful.

```
const App =() =>{

const[inHoverControl , setInHoverControl]= React.useState(false)
const[isControlOpen, setIsControlOpen] = React.useState(true);
const [isImgOpen, setIsImgOpen] = React.useState(false);

 function openControl(){
      setIsControlOpen(true)
    }
    function closeControl(){
      setIsControlOpen(false)
    }

return (

     <div>
        <div onMouseLeave={() => setInHoverImg(false)}onMouseEnter={() => setInHoverImg(true)}  
           className={"menu__iconsRight " + ((isControlOpen) ? "active": "")}   >
            <img  className='taskbar__iconsRight'  onClick={() => setIsControlOpen((isControlOpen) => 
              !isControlOpen)} 
              src="https://winaero.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Col-wind0- 
               icon.png"/>
             {isControlOpen ? <Control closeControl={closeControl}  />: null}
             
             {isImgOpen ? 
              <div>
               {inHoverPanel && 
                <div onClick={()=> setIsControlOpen((!isControlOpen))} className='hover__container'>                            
                  <GrClose   className='close' onClick={() => {
                    setIsImgOpen(!isImgOpen);
                     }} />                        
                    <img  className='hover__control'src="./images/icons/control1.png" />
                </div>}              
                   </div>:null}
                     </div>
                        </div>



)
}
```

Comment: Could you create a working jsfiddle so we can do some easy testing here?

Comment: Ok. I will in 5 min

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-satoshi-flkc5

Comment: Sorry mate, but the codesandbox gives all kinds of errors. If that's the case on your side as well, I am gonna ask you to fix it first so I won't have to spend a bunch of time just fixing the sandbox.

Comment: @ThaekeHekkenberg https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-water-vj5im